# How to tell TypeScript the type of my object?

Tags: typescript

Let's start with some code:

```
export function toArrayStrict(obj: Iterable<any>): any[] {
    if(obj) {
        if(isArray(obj)) {
            return obj; // error TS2322: Type 'Iterable<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

        }
        if(isFunction(obj[Symbol.iterator])) {
            return [...obj];
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`Cannot convert ${getType(obj)} to array; it is not iterable.`);
}
```

This is throwing an error when I try to compile it:

> error TS2322: Type 'Iterable' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Which I totally get. It doesn't know that I've verified `obj` is in fact `any[]`.

My question is, how do I tell the compiler that `isArray` is checking the type, and this is actually safe to do?

**Note,** I know the error will go away if I use `Array.isArray` instead. This question is not about that. I want to know how I tell `tsc` what the type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isArray(obj: any): obj is Array<any> {
    return obj instanceof Array;
}

function isFunction(obj: any): obj is Function {
    return typeof obj === "function";
}

if (isArray(obj)) {
    return obj; // should be fine now
}
```

Comment: Awww man, that's awesome!! I didn't actually think TS would have a solution for this. Just discovered I could [suppress](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448#issuecomment-229739856) the error, but this is much better.

Comment: Using `any` will cause you to lose type safety. You should do so only when you really have no other choice.